# Advanced search engine for MySQL that doesn't require unique INT and covers multiple tables

Tags: mysql, search, solr, sphinx

Recently I developed a piece of software that downloads logfiles from our online production environment to an internal NAS device with a MySQL database to enable us to store more information (online space is expensive). This thing has been up and running for two weeks now, so our database is growing:
Number of log tables    411 
Number of log entries   48,000,513
Approx. size of tables: 37.32 GB

Every hour a different logtable is created (with over 100.000 entries every time), that's why we have 411 at the moment.

I also created a search interface for it, using an index table which contains table names, the first and the last entry in the table, so that when specifying a date for the search, things run quite smooth.

However when I search for e.g. "site X" without specifying a date range, over 400 tables have to be searched, and every row contains a large XML message, so things are getting slower every day.

I started looking for more advanced search solutions and found them with Sphinx and Solr, BUT I just can't seem to get things right:

- I can't find how to set up those engines to search across all tables (they all have the same structure). -- I could overcome this by dynamically creating a huge view, or merging the tables programmatically for now and add new records to a single table in the future, so that isn't really the big issue.
- I tried Sphinx, but it requires an integer as a primary key - and we have GUID's (the online table is MSSQL)... I could always add a numeric index to overcome this, but I don't want to :)
- I tried Solr, I set it up to search in one of the 411 tables but I didn't get any results. After it did the indexing, it told me X records were indexed (about 12,000), which seemed right. However, I didn't find out how to actually search it.

Bottomline of my question(s):

- Is there a more 'handy' GUI available to search on Solr, since that was the one in which I got the furthest except for the searching part
- Or is there a way to set up Sphinx with char(32) as index?
- Isn't there some kind of search engine which takes care of all this 'mess' for me, since I could merge everything into one table, it would just have to search one table?
- Are there any other search engines (preferably free) I should look into?
- Would it be a good idea to create a single large table to ease my work? So roughly calculated it would consist of 1,248,013,338 or 970,32 GB after a year (at least, since the amount of logfiles per hour would only increase). If I'm doing this completely the wrong way, please tell me.

I hope my I clarified my problem enough. Thanks in advance.

edit: In het meanwhile, I was able to set up Solr and was able to search it. However it creates an index which is almost the size of the original table.. so I guess I should stick to my own home-brewed search engine..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

( have no experience with solr so cant help you there)

> Or is there a way to set up Sphinx with char(32) as index?

Sphinx just requires a unique id. It doesn't actually have to match the database primary key!

- You can store it (the real) in attributes so get it back when searching.

A couple of ways to get an id:

- make a fake one!

  sql_query_pre = SET @id = 1
  sql_query = SELECT @id := @id+1,...
- use hashing

  sql_query = SELECT CRC32(uuid),...

  Although http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2008/03/09/a-very-fast-fnv-hash-function-for-mysql/ may be even better, and used with --enable-id64 in sphinx. The chance of a collision is small (but non existent)
- use only a part of the uuid. Depends on how the original is created - eg if they have a common prefix.
- If using a innodb table to store data, mysql will have created an integer id for the data already. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/sorting-rows.html

(Sphinx also has a few tricks to help with indexing large numbers of tables. The config 'file' can actually be a script. That way can have a script just output a large number of very similar index definitions. And a single index, can have many 'sources'. So a single index, can easily draw content from a number of source tables. This helps, because while sphinx can have hundreds of tables, its a lot of overhead, so might be worth grouping them. Say 24 tables/sources per index. )